# Mix Scala Option and regular variable in a statement

Tags: scala, dsl, implicit

I would like to write conditional statements mixing transparently Scala Options and regular variables.
For example:

```
var o1 = Some(1)
var o2: Option[Int] = None

var x = 2

val test1 = x < 3 && o1<5  //=> should be true or Some(true)
val test2 = x < 3 && o2<5  //=> should be false or None
val test3 = x < 3 || o2<5  //=> should be true (o2 not evaluated)
```

of course I could write

```
 test1 = x < 3 && o1.exists (_<5)
```

but I would prefer a cleaner syntax.

Any hint? Should I expand 'Option' with operators, or use implicits, or category theory or else?

Answer (score 4):

Using implicits is certainly easy:

```
implicit def enrichOptionInt(self: Option[Int]) = new {
  def <(i: Int) = self.exists(_ < i)
}

val test1 = x < 3 && o1 < 5  // True
```

Or if you want it to work for any kind of Numeric:

```
class EnrichedOptionNumeric[N: Numeric](self: Option[N]) {
  def <(n: N) = self.exists(v => implicitly[Numeric[N]].lt(v, n))
}
implicit def enrichOptionNumeric[N: Numeric](self: Option[N]) = new EnrichedOptionNumeric(self)

val oD = Some(2.0)
val test1 = x < 3 && o1 < 5    // true
val testD = x < 3 && oD < 5.0  // true
```

**EDIT** to answer question in comment:

If you want to support equality, you, unfortunately, cannot use `==` since that operator is already defined for `Option`.  If a method (or operator) is already defined for a class, then the implicit will never be triggered since Scala only looks for implicits when it doesn't recognize the method being called.

You *can* however, simply define a different symbol to mean "option equals".  For example, you could use `===`.  To do so, you'd just add the following line to the definition of `EnrichedOptionNumeric` above:

```
def ===(n: N) = self.exists(v => implicitly[Numeric[N]].equiv(v, n))
```

Then you can do:

```
val testE = x < 3 && o1 === 1 // true
```

Comment: The general solution is not yet 'easy' for me ... Thanks !

Comment: A question : is it possible to have the equality test ? (==)

Answer (score 4):

What about mapping from `Option[Int]` to `Option[Boolean]`?

```
x < 3 && (o1 map {_ < 5} getOrElse false)
x < 3 && (o2 map {_ < 5} getOrElse false)
x < 3 || (o2 map {_ < 5} getOrElse false)
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is a *cleaner syntax*

Comment: @om-nom-nom: true, I just find it slightly more idiomatic compared to `exists()` (?). BTW thx for edit.

Answer (score 1):

Think about whether there's a more natural way to express the "missing" value in the context of this problem than using an `Option`. Maybe to say there's no limit, a `Double` with a value of `Infinity` would work, or an `Int` with `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Then remove the `Option` from the problem completely. If you can't then you can use

```
var o1 = Some (1)
var o2 = Option[Int] = None

var x = 2

val test1 = x < 3 && o1.getOrElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE)<5  //=> should be true or Some(true)
val test2 = x < 3 && o2.getOrElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE)<5  //=> should be false or None
val test3 = x < 3 || o2.getOrElse(Integer.MAX_VALUE)<5  //=> should be true (o2 not evaluated)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomasz Nurkiewicz's answer can be made more succinct with some [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) sugar, and by employing the `Monoid` instance for `Boolean`.

The "zero" value  for the monoid is `false`, so `o getOrElse false` becomes `~o`, using a unary operator `~` defined in scalaz. (Here I am using scalaz 6.0.4)

```
def p: Int => Boolean = _ < 3
def q: Int => Boolean = _ < 5
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

scala> val test1 = p(x) && ~(o1 map q)
test1: Boolean = true

scala> val test2 = p(x) && ~(o2 map q)
test2: Boolean = false

scala> val test3 = p(x) || ~(o2 map q)
test3: Boolean = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala can actually make an Ordering for Option[A] if you have an Ordering[A] but the semantics are different (None is the smallest value) from what you wanted.

Also, for the comparison to work, both values need to be of the same type, so you need a way to lift the Ints into an Option. I added an opt method for that purpose.

This is an example with the internal ordering:

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits.infixOrderingOps
//This allows you to use method/operator syntax on anything with an Ordering

implicit def mkOption[A](a: A) = new { def opt: Option[A] = Some(a) }

var o1 = Some(1)
var o2: Option[Int] = None

var x = 2

val test1 = x < 3 && o1<5.opt  //=> true
val test2 = x < 3 && o2<5.opt  //=> true
val test3 = x < 3 || o2<5.opt  //=> true
None > 0.opt //=> false
None < 0.opt //=> true
```

To get closer to your semantics, we can define a new ordering

```
implicit def mkOptionOrdering[A: Ordering] = new Ordering[Option[A]] {
    def compare(a: Option[A], b: Option[A]): Int = {
      if (a.isEmpty || b.isEmpty) 0 
      else implicitly[Ordering[A]].compare(a.get, b.get)
    }
  }
```

Now your tests will do what you expected and the 2 extra tests will also be false but those semantics are rather odd, compare returns 0 for things that aren't equal.

Comment: The semantic is not 'odd', IMO, if you consider 'None' as an undefined value in a rule, ie a statement that is true if all values are known and condition is true.
Anyway, thanks for the hint.

Comment: I suppose odd might be the wrong word. I meant it may throw people off when compare and equals don't agree. It's worth putting a warning somewhere, I think.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html